# SSDP Search in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8, upnp, ssdp

I'm new at SSDP/UPNP/Sockets and all that jazz. I'm playing around with it a bit and I just want to see what a generic SSDP search on my network will bring up.

Using this [SSDP Sniffer](http://www.windowsphone.com/s?appid=934168d7-f476-40a6-a42b-e0f4a56dae84) app, I get a lot of results so I'm attempting to recreate this.

I'm using the following code, which I've found various versions of, but all the tweaking I do doesn't appear to bring back any results. I pretty much at a loss here and would appreciate any guidance.

thanks!

```
private const string SSDP_IP = "239.255.255.250";
private const string SSDP_PORT = "1900";
private const string SSDP_QUERY = "M-SEARCH * HTTP/1.1\r\n" +
                                  "Host: " + SSDP_IP + ":" + SSDP_PORT + "\r\n" +
                                  "Man: ssdp:discover\r\n" +
                                  "ST: ssdp:all\r\n";

DataGramSocket socket;

async public void SsdpQueryAsync()
{
    var remoteIP = new Windows.Networking.HostName(SSDP_IP);
    var reqBuff = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(SSDP_QUERY);

    socket = new DatagramSocket();

    socket.MessageReceived += (sender, args) =>
    {
        // This is invoked for each device that responds to the query...
        Task.Run(() =>
            {
                 // do something useful
            });
    };

    await socket.BindEndpointAsync(null, "");

    socket.JoinMulticastGroup(remoteIP);

    using (var stream = await socket.GetOutputStreamAsync(remoteIP, SSDP_PORT))
    {
        await stream.WriteAsync(reqBuff.AsBuffer());
    }

    await Task.Delay(5000);
}
```

Comment: What does "doesn't appear to bring back any results" mean? Do you get an error? and empty buffer returned? something else?

Comment: no messages are ever received back so socket.MessageReceived is never triggered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with C# or dotnet APIs, but I can see some details wrong with the M-SEARCH message:

- MAN header must be enclosed in double quotes, so `MAN: "ssdp:discover"\r\n`
- MX header is missing (required for multicast)
- USER-AGENT header is missing
- missing an empty line in the end
- Header names are supposedly case insensitive, but I'd use upper case just in case...

See the [Device Architecture reference pdf](http://upnp.org/specs/arch/UPnP-arch-DeviceArchitecture-v1.1.pdf) for more details

Comment: I had tried it with double quotes in the MAN header. I had the MX header in there (not sure why I didn't in this post). I had previously tried making all header names upper case. What solved it was the empty line in the end. WOW!