# Did Windows 8.1 change SSDP discovery?

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-8.1, service-discovery, ssdp

I implemented [discovery using SSDP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18834893/ssdp-search-in-windows-phone-8) in my Windows 8 app, and all was fine and dandy. I updated to 8.1 yesterday and now discovery is no longer working. Now when I call `await socket.GetOutputStreamAsync(multicastIP, SSDP_PORT)` I'm getting a System.Exception: *No such host is known. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80072AF9)*.

Has anybody else run into this? Was something locked down in 8.1?

**update 1/23**: looks like it may be a problem with my proj file getting corrupted. I'm able to create a new project and discovery works again, but after a while *I start getting the exception again*. I'm still not sure what is causing this and if it is a problem with my dev environment or a change in Win 8.

Even if I close out and reboot, when I bring the project up again, it still throws the exception.

**update 1/24**: seems to be an issue with my network adapters. I don't know much about this stuff, but my WiFi adapter was bridged, and when I removed it from the bridge, it worked again.

Perhaps someone smarter than me will be able to figure this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not SSDP or Socket specific. Issue was related to bridged network adapters. See update 1/24.